# Add new Items in a combo box in access

Tags: ms-access, autocomplete, combobox, ms-access-2007

im new to access 2007

I have 3 tables and One Form..i have **Accounts**,***IT*** and **Software** tables..i have created each table and enter a values for them(ID,Description).. i have another table called **Faculty** which i have the ***AccountsID***,***AccountsDesc***,***ITDesc*** and ***SoftwareDesc*** as attributes in my  **combo box** form.So when i did my Query all working fine.even if Accounts Desc start with first character as 'F' it able to pick it up..because Finance was already entered in my database..My Question i want to add a new Accounts Name on the combo box without add from the database?..so that it can be saved in my drop down list if its selected again.. i try many ways but i cant..anyone can solve my problems?..

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your form, or the code you use to run your combo box?

Answer (score 1):

You can only have your combo list come automatically from a table, or by entering it manually into a value list. You can't do both.

So, to solve your problem, you'll have to use VBA. I'm just going to give you the rough steps here. You'll be ale to search for details if you don't know how to do a step.

In the **Form_Load** event, you'll build your list. 
You'll do this by opening the table or query that has the values you want in your list, reading it one record at a time, and entering the value into your combo box.
The command for adding an item to the combobox is **ComboboxName.AddItem** ***value***.
Then add your additional value you want. **ComboboxName.AddItem** ***"New Account"***

Good luck